# How can I remap windows and alt keys in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, windows-key

I sometimes hook up my macbook to a windows keyboard. The annoying thing is that on windows keyboards the modifier keys at the lower left are layout as

```
ctrl - windows - alt
```

while apple keyboards use

```
ctrl - alt - apple
```

The windows key functions as the apple key, the problem is that they are located at a different location, and my muscle memory is so set on finding the 'command' key next to the spacebar that I keep executing my shortcuts with alt i.s.o. apple key (and vice versa)

Short of buying an Apple keyboard, does anyone know a way to remap both keys in osx?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

- In System Preferences | Keyboard | Modifier Keys you can swap these two keys.
- [Double Command](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a PrefPane that offers many options for using Windows-keyboards (see the 3d & 4h checkboxes in the screenshot on that page).  I'm not sure it offers advantages over the standard keyboard preferences, but perhaps it includes automatic sensning or a quicker way (hot key?) of changing back and forth.

Comment: What I find interesting is that you can change it per keyboard (so you can make it different for the laptop keyboard and the external keyboard)

Comment: This solution may no longer be effective - I could not get the built-in Modifier Keys solution to work on Yosemite (OS X 10.10) with a Corsair K70 keyboard. [This answer provides an external solution](http://superuser.com/a/273288/206256) which I found worked well, and is the suggested replacement for the linked Double Command.

Comment: For what it's worth, making the changes under Modifier Keys worked for me. I'm using a Logitech K350 and running OS X El Capitan 10.11.4.

Comment: Working for Sierra, too.

Comment: Working for me in Oct '20 and Catalina for my external keyboard. With that setup it is actually essential to select the keyboard you are modifying.

Comment: Worked for me on Catalina 10.15

Comment: Works for me in Big Sur 11.6.5.  Just be sure to select the right keyboard! My mouse appears in the "Select keyboard" dropdown, and all attempts to change the mouse's control key failed lol

Answer (score 41):

Under the Keyboard System Preferences pane there is a button for "Modifier Keys" which allows you to remap command/option/control on a per-keyboard basis. There is no need to use an external tool to switch the keys.

[image: Modifier keys screenshot]

I'm using OSX El Capitan and Microsoft Sculpt keyboard.

Comment: This is a great answer, nice that this is a mac native option.

Answer (score 7):

This question still pops up when searching today. Steps seem to have changed slightly in newer versions of macOS.

You need to go to System Settings > Keyboard
[image: Keyboard settings in System Settings]

Click on Keyboard Shortcuts... then select Modifier Keys
[image: Modifier Keys in Keyboard Shortcuts]

Make sure you have selected the right keyboard from the dropdown on top. From there, you can manually swap Option key to be Command, and Command key to be Option.