# Remapping windows and alt keys on Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite under Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to swap the function of the windows (command) and alt (option) keys on my Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite under Snow Leopard. I tried changing the mapping under System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys... I verified that "Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite" was selected in the drop down, and then I swaped the function of the Command and Option keys in the menu, but it doesn't have any affect, even after restarting. How can I get this to work?

Comment: It should work... it works on my keyboard at least. Are you sure you pressed "ok" after swapping functions? :D

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/158561/how-can-i-remap-windows-and-alt-keys-in-os-x; same answer.

Comment: It's not a duplicate... it's about why the first part of the "duplicate" answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why you two guys seem to be getting two different results. It's because you're trying the result on two different ends of the keyboard.

I'm running Snow Leopard and temporarily had to swap in an MS Keyboard Elite. What I found was, that after making the System Preference change, it successfully swapped the Command and Option keys to the right of the spacebar, but ignored them (didn't swap) to the left of the spacebar. Arrgh!

And of course Microsoft's Intellitype driver, which can convert some of their keyboard to Mac use just fine, doesn't work with their Elite keyboard at all. Who knows why. Thanks, Microsoft!